# Color in JCreator

Tags: java, colors, ansi-escape, jcreator

When trying to use the ANSI escape codes, it would not work. I would assume this is because `JCreator` does not support these escape codes. Is there any other way to print out color when using `System.out.println`? The ANSI codes I am using is below along with what I am trying to print as a trial. The code is inside a class and it is running properly.

```
final String ANSI_RESET = "\u001B[0m";
final String ANSI_BLACK = "\u001B[30m";
final String ANSI_RED = "\u001B[31m";
final String ANSI_GREEN = "\u001B[32m";
final String ANSI_YELLOW = "\u001B[33m";
final String ANSI_BLUE = "\u001B[34m";
final String ANSI_PURPLE = "\u001B[35m";
final String ANSI_CYAN = "\u001B[36m";
final String ANSI_WHITE = "\u001B[37m";
System.out.println(ANSI_RED + "This text is red!" + ANSI_RESET);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of color with System.out. Its an abstraction that is used to output text to any kind of target, be it the console of an IDE, a file or a NULL target that discards the output.

ANSI codes are understood *only* by an ANSI compatible console, for example the windows command line prompt. So *if* you run your code from cmd (without redirecting the output), you will see the codes take effect. In your IDE's console they wont.